# free(): invalid pointer at 2nd element

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I am getting a

> free(): invalid pointer:

when attempting to free the 2nd address allocated in db->rows (marked //ERROR below)

```
typedef struct {
    int max_data;
    int max_rows;
    Address *rows;
} Database;

void Database_create(Connection *conn) {
    conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(Address) * conn->db->max_rows);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < conn->db->max_rows; i++) {
        Address *rows = conn->db->rows;
        rows[i] = *Address_create(i, 0);
    }
}

void Database_destroy(Database *db) {
    if (db) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < db->max_rows; i++) {
            Address_destroy(&db->rows[i]);
        }
    }
}

Address *Address_create(int id, int set) {
    Address *addr = malloc(sizeof(Address));
    addr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_data);
    addr->email = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_data);
    addr->id = id;
    addr->set = set;
    return addr;
}

void Address_destroy(Address *addr) {
    if (addr) {
        if (addr->name) free(addr->name);
        if (addr->email) free(addr->email);
        free(addr); // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: My tip: remove the start in  `rows[i] = *Address_create(i, 0);` .

Comment: that makes it not compile with:error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Address’ from type ‘struct Address *’

Comment: @Marian I agree that you've identified the problem in the code. But the suggested change is not going to be enough (it won't even compile). The struct also needs to be changed to declare `rows` as `Address **rows`. And other changes throughout the code to match that.

Comment: Because `&db->rows[i]` is not a pointer to the start of a memory block allocated by `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement does not look like a valid one, which copies the content of the allocated pointer and not the allocated pointer itself.

```
rows[i] = *Address_create(i, 0);
```

You many need to change your datatype of conn->db->rows to `Adress **` and then allocate memory as below

```
conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(Address *) * conn->db->max_rows);
```

And then set rows[i] as below

```
rows[i] = Address_create(i, 0);
```

And then free each row as below

```
Address_destroy(db->rows[i]);
```

Also change all references to rows[i] as per the changed data type.

Comment: Yes, i declared incorrectly  Adress *rows wanting to have an array of pointers to address